# UNIX shell script fails when ran as a scheduled task

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, wget

I'm having 1 small issue with a shell script failing to perform one of the commands listed in an IF statement.

**The script is 100% functional if you open a terminal window and copy\paste the entire script.**

If you just run the script by calling to it, everything works **except** this line which you will see at the very bottom:

> echo $newID > $fileID

The environment is Windows Server 2012 running GitBASH. (That will explain the C:/ file paths)

Any ideas as to why the script fails to perform that 1 task only when ran as a "script" compared to copy\pasting the code into terminal?

---

Here's the entire script.
Thank you

```
# Clean directory
cd C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/
rm -f C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/*.csv

# <---- Define: Date variables (not all dates used but available if needed \ just modify the wget string) ----> #

twoDaysAgo=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '2 days ago')
yesterday=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d 'yesterday')
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
tomorrow=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d 'tomorrow')

# <---- Define: Date timestamp variables for file naming ----> #
stampTwoDaysAgo=$(date +%m-%d-%Y -d '2 days ago')
stampTomorrow=$(date +%m-%d-%Y -d 'tomorrow')

# <---- Define: Credentials variable  ----> #
account="--http-user=APIuser --http-password=APIpassword"

# <---- Define: Export output directory variable  ----> #
sourceFile="C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/currentLastID.csv"
output=$"C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/"${stampTwoDaysAgo}"_"${stampTomorrow}".csv"
tempIDsource=$"C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/archive/"${stampTwoDaysAgo}"_"${stampTomorrow}".csv"

# <---- Define: Export lastID variable  ----> #
callID=$(awk -F'","|^"|"$' 'BEGIN { max=0 } $1 > max { max=$1 } END {print max}' "C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/ID/ID.txt")

# <---- Execute WGET function to export Shoretel calls from the specified date range ----> #
wget --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate --output-document=${output} "https://portal.shoretelsky.com/DataExport/CDRData?startDate=${twoDaysAgo}&endDate=${tomorrow}&lastId=${callID}" ${account}

# Perform empty file validation, if file is 0 kb the script will terminate and retry
if [ -s "$output" ]
then
    echo "File is not empty continue to next IF statement"
else
    ./retry.sh
fi


#### At this point we should have a valid file 1 kb or larger. If the export contains 0 new records the script will terminate and the previous callID will remain ####

# Define tempID to check for invalid or empty ID field
tempID=$(awk -F'","|^"|"$' 'BEGIN { max=0 } $18 > max { max=$18 } END {print max}' $output)

# Define ID paramaters and rename files
fileID="C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/ID/ID.txt"

if [ "$tempID" -gt "$callID" ]
then
    cp $output C:/Scripts/Shoretel_Export/output/archive/
    mv $output $sourceFile
    newID=$(awk -F'","|^"|"$' 'BEGIN { max=0 } $18 > max { max=$18 } END {print max}' $tempIDsource)
    echo $newID > $fileID
    echo "Export and Timestamp complete"
else
    echo "Export contains 0 new call records \ the script will now terminate"
fi
```

Comment: Make sure it runs as a scheduled task using the same user you use when you run it in the console. Or make sure the `System` user (or whatever user runs the scheduled tasks; I don't have a Windows system at hand) has the rights needed to write the file.

Comment: I knew it had to be some issue with the Windows task. I'll update the question to show how I got it working. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED:** *The issue was with the scheduled task in Windows. Here's what I did to get it working.*

> Task Scheduler > Modify the schedule to: Start a Program > Program/Script:
>   **cmd** Add arguments (optional): **/K
>   C:\Scripts\Shoretel_Export\Shoretel-Export.sh & exit**

---

Comment: You should mark the question as answered if it is so :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its gonna work on windows but you should try execute the script in debug mode:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

So you can check line by line what is happen.
Also could you show also the output of this script?

Comment: The output of the script is a call log .csv file. Nothing special but it contains information I feel is confidential so I can't share it.

I've tried that. If you already have the terminal window open and run "bash -x ./Export.sh" the script will complete without any issues.

Only when the script is run headless does it fail to perform that 1 .txt file update via the ECHO > command.